# imageIO giving error?

Tags: java, image

```
 public BufferedImage readImage(String fileLocation) {
        BufferedImage img = null;

        File file = new File("D:\\logo.jpg");
            img = ImageIO.read(file);
}
```

throwing error can;t read the file

Comment: What is the Stack trace? Does the file exist in the provided location?

Comment: Please copy the exact error message as produced by `printStackTrace()` and add it as an edit to the question.  BTW - what is your question (adding a '?' to the title does not make it a question)?  Why is the `fileLocation` specified as an argument when the code goes on to load a `File` from a hard-coded `String`?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (and upload the image to somewhere we can see it).

Comment: The first posted code would compile, whereas the code in the latest edit would not.  Please take more care when doing edits.

Comment: 2012-03-15 12:59:52,453 ERROR [STDERR] javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
2012-03-15 12:59:52,453 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1279)

Comment: *"javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!"*  A call to `printStackTrace` will generally produce the exact file name it was trying to load, and not include a gratuitous '!'.  What tool are you using to run this code?  Which part of *"add it as an edit to the question"* do you not understand?  Note that Java's file names are case sensitive, so **logo.jpg** `!=` **Logo.jpg**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be like as follows,

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
     img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\logo.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Exception is --- "+ e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you can trace actual cause of the problem as we are printing message and stack trace if exception occurs.